# How can I match features with FAST Algorithm?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

```
# Initiate FAST object
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create(threshold=25)

# find and draw the keypoints
kp1 = fast.detect(img1, None)
kp2 = fast.detect(img2, None)
img1_corners = cv2.drawKeypoints(img1, kp1, None, color=(255, 0, 0))
img2_corners = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2, kp2, None, color=(255, 0, 0))
```

I have the keypoints now? How can I match them? I only want to know if it is in the picture or not. Rough position would be nice too.
(It isn't rotated or anything, that's why I'm using FAST and not SURF or something)

Comment: Show your input images. Draw the keypoints. Read the literature. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html

Comment: for matching you need some kind of descriptor. You can use any descriptor (e.g. sift/surf/orb) or invent something that fits best to your special task.